# Tab through a table inside content editable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to tab through HTML tables cells inside a contenteditable div. I know most people would say why are you doing that in the first place. I am working on a text editor that allows the user to insert a pre-formatted table where ever they want. I have tackled inserting the table dynamically at the users cursor but I cannot figure out how to let the user tab from the content to the html table and through each cell. I have tried input boxes which allows them to tab through but it leaves selector bars on each corner and still requires the user to double click on the cell to add content. I have also tried just table cells and it will not tab to the cells it just jumps over them. Any help would be much appreciated... after conquering the tracking of the cursor for inserting the table I thought I was home free... :(

```
  <div id="divbilltext" runat="server" contenteditable="true" style="height:auto;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <input type="text" id="a" tabindex="1"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="text" id="b" tabindex="2"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="text" id="c" tabindex="3"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                      </div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex

Comment: The w3schools is ok for beginners but rubbish for advanced users

Comment: I guess I should have given more detail... the above code in on a vb.net page... the links above did not help me as I have done the inputs with ids etc. It will tab through them but it puts selector bars on them and will not let the user input data in them unless they double click on them. I am not a complete newbie so I have down basic tab index stuff.... Something is going on weird on my page.... Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

tabindex would be the most consistent way of achieving this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

however tabindex is supported by specific elements only: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Comment: Ok please check out my code now. It has the correct tabindex and ids for the inputs... as stated in my original post this will allow tabbing but it puts selector bars on the input boxes when you tab through then and does not let the user enter data until they double click on the input box... so tabbing will work but not really as the user cannot input data... I know its something simple I am missing please help! :)

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the div causing the problem... If I take it out of the div it works fine but inside the div... no go... any thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out my self. I just nested the table inside another div with contenteditable set to false... not sure why it worked but it did :)